# How to break a long line in a hover text Plotly?

Tags: python, text, plotly

I have a hover text that contains a long line (about 200 characters). The problem is that it becomes a long rectangle through the whole figure and it is not possible to see the complete text because it cuts.

My data is in a dataframe. I am plotting x and y and just adding a z variable that contains description in the hover text.

[image: Picture of my plot]

Is it possible to adjust the high and width of the text box? Or could I break the text in several lines?

This is my code at the moment:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,column_widths=[1], 
                    subplot_titles=["A", "B"])
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.varA,
        y=df.varB,
        hovertext = df.varC,
        marker=dict(color='darkblue'),
        mode = 'markers'
    ), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
       x=df.varA,
        y=df.varB,
        hovertext = df.varC,
        marker=dict(color='darkblue'),
        mode = 'markers'
        ), row=2, col=1)


fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',showlegend=False, height=900, width=1000,title_text="Example")
fig.show()
```

Please help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://plot.ly/python/hover-text-and-formatting/), it seems that strings support HTML markup.

So you could add some `<br>` tags into you string to break lines:

```py
label = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>Sed eget arcu sit amet purus volutpat euismod sed id quam.
```

Comment: For who is interested, I now used: hovertext = df.varC.apply(lambda txt: '<br>'.join(textwrap.wrap(txt, width=50)))

Answer (score 13):

Since plotly reads in html including tags, you can insert `\n` and the break tag `<br>` into the text for the df variable you want to have wrap when displayed:

```py
df.varA = df.varA.str.wrap(30)
df.varA = df.varA.apply(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '<br>'))
```

Comment: In one line: `hovertext = df.varC.str.wrap(30).apply(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '<br>'))`

Comment: I love you @mChristos :)